# How to extend background CSS styling indefinitely along the x-axis?

Tags: html, css

I have a header background that I would like to bleed indefinitely on the x axis. So regardless of the size of someones monitor, the grey background would extend.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to either stretch your header horizontally, or apply the background onto `html` (or `body`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers, depending on what issue you're exactly facing.

### First case:

#### The background isn't repeating at all

Assuming you're using a CSS `background-image` to render your background, use `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/PdFnJ/).

If you're not using a `background-image` to render your background, then you should consider using it. There's no direct way of making an `<img>` repeat.

### Second case:

#### The background is repeating, it's just not spanning the whole width

You need to make sure your `header` has `width: 100%;`. If you have some padding to your `header`s parent, use `display: block;` instead of `width: 100%;`, otherwise it'll overflow.

Comment: Aww, what happened to your `background-repeat-x: repeat`? I hadn't actually looked to see if that was a valid property but I was curious.

Comment: @canon Nope, it isn't a valid property.

Comment: @canon: I think it was a typo.

Comment: Hey, it's a css styling. "background:" - How do I make THAT repeat? Coded graphics.

Comment: @EvanB It's the same. `background` is just shorthand for a bunch of `background` properties, including `background-image`. If you want to do it in shorthand, you can do this: `background: _background-definition-here_ repeat-x;`.

Comment: @EvanB It'd be useful if you provide a demo or your CSS.